# Eclipse Luna - Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I downloaded Eclipse Luna, started it then went to install new software

https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4

Downloaded all of the plugins, but nothing for Androids SDK appeared.

When I start Eclipse it says I need to update my Android SDK location preferences.

Could I get some assistance as to where to find it in my eclipse directory, or where to download the ADT package. Previous versions have included ADT within it, but I've failed to find a version of Luna that does.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only Eclipse Version with ADT incluced is Juno yet.
You can try to download the single ADT-Plugin in Eclipse: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse
If you have the Android SDK installed you also have to add the directories "tools" and "platform-tools" to your environment path.